# jQuery: Show/Hide table rows

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to show hide table rows by assigning a number id to the class attribute of the tr element

I have it coded so that the first instance of this number id is shown while the rest are hidden. Clicking the first instance should reveal the rest of the rows with the same id.

This is the code I have so far, however it fails to reveal the rest of the rows:

The following code is in the document.ready function

```
var ids = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"];

        var i;

        for (i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {


             $("." + ids[i]).hide()

             $("." + ids[i] + ":first").show()

             $("." + ids[i] + ":first").click(function () {

                if( $("." + ids[i] + ":last").css('display') == 'none') {

                    $("." + ids[i]).show()

                } else {

                     $("." + ids[i]).hide()

                     $("." + ids[i] + ":first").show()

                }

            });


        }
```

The html is just

```
<tr class="<%= @current_id %>">
<td>test data</td>
<td>test data</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Adding your code to http://jsfiddle.net/ would be great

Comment: so would adding the html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have many errors:

```
$("." + ids[i] + ":first")
to
$("." + ids[i]).first()
```

then

```
if( $("." + ids[i] + ":last").css('display') == 'none')

to 

if( $("." + ids[i]).last().is(':visible'))
```

then close all methods with `";"` :

```
$("." + ids[i]).show()
```

to

```
$("." + ids[i]).show();
```

also the class `.1` or `.2` etc .. are not valid you should replace that with `.1-row`

then , actually you are selecting all the `tr` but not the `td` elements, you should do somenthing like:

```
$("."+ids[i]).children('td').first().....ect /*this select the first td of the tr*/
```

Comment: ok i've done all that and it's still not revealing the other rows

Comment: @Dave i updated the answer, are you selecting tr childs? this *$("." + ids[i])* is selecting the *tr* element not the *td*, use *$("."+ids[i]).children('td').first()* for example

Comment: you need to replace that with your, check the answer